# How do I skip tables when I use range.find to search the entire document using vsto?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

Now I want to traverse the whole word document through range.find. I need to skip the tables in the document and then do automatic typesetting of the traversed characters, but I haven't found a way to exclude the tables. Is there any way to solve this problem?

Information[WdInformation.wdWithInTable]

```cs
  Range sRange=Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.Selection.Range
  Range fR = wordDoc.Range(sRange.Start, sRange.End);
                fR.Find.ClearFormatting();
                fR.Find.Text = "[a-zA-Z0-9]{1,}";
                fR.Find.Replacement.ClearFormatting();
                fR.Find.MatchWildcards = true;

                //fR.Find.Wrap = WdFindWrap.wdFindContinue;
                fR.Find.Forward = true;

                object missing = Type.Missing;
                fR.Find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                    ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                while (fR.Find.Found)
                {
                    int rs = fR.Start;
                    int re = fR.End;

                    if (rs > sRange.End || re < sRange.Start) break;
                    //if (fR.Information[WdInformation.wdWithInTable])
                    //    continue;

                    fR.Font.Size = (float)tsd.content.enfont.size;
                    fR.Font.Name = tsd.content.enfont.face;
                    fR.Find.Execute(ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing,
                        ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
                }
```

I hope the typesetting data will not affect the table in any way,but it is useless.

Comment: You show `Information[WdInformation.wdWithInTable]` in the question, before the code. This would certainly be relevant, what is the problem with using it? For example `while (fR.Find.Found && fR.get_Information(WdInformation.wdWithInTable)`

Comment: I find it at https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/dotnet/api/microsoft.office.interop.word.wdinformation?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=word-pia,but I don't know if I need to use wdWithInTable.

Answer (score 1):

It's possible to use `Word.WdInformation.wdWithInTable` to determine whether a `Range` or `Selection` is in a table.

In the Word COM world, this is a property named `Information` that takes various parameters and returns different kinds of information (boolean, integers, etc.) Since C# doesn't support properties that take parameters this is converted to the `get_Information` method in the PIAs. Also, since the return values are not all the same data type, the method returns an `object`, which means the value returned needs to be explicitly cast.

The following code snippet, based on the code in the question, shows how to test whether the found `Range` is not in a table.

```
while (fR.Find.Found && !(bool)fR.get_Information(Word.WdInformation.wdWithInTable))
{
    Debug.Print("Not in a table");
}
```